# Android Google+ Api sign in

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-plus

I'm trying to develop a app that uses google+ to login

I have seen the documentation here [Google Plus Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)
my problem now is that the sign up button is only for @gmail.com domain if I sign in using our domain @example.com it's not working

Comment: Is your account using your domain @example.com a gmail account?

Comment: I'm using our company's own domain... and it's working on google+ website but on google+ api it's not working

Comment: What happens if you try using the OAuth 2.0 Playground [ https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ ] while signed in with your company account?  Are you able to authorize the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login scope and make a request?  eg. a request for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible

Comment: Hi lee thanks for the reply... I'm new in google+ api and I dont know how to use scope is there a guide that I can use so that I'll have an idea on how to use scope

Comment: Does your company domain run on Google Apps, I take it?  If so, does your company domain have Google+ enabled?  What do you see when you go to plus.google.com?  (Note, not all domains have enabled Google+.)

Comment: our companies domain (sonarlogic.biz) run on plus.google.com (WEB) but when I'm signing in on Android Phone it doesn't work and I'm still a OJT student so I really dont know about our company